# Circular plot with related temperature

Tags: python-3.6

Hello guys and thanks in advance for your time.
I'm trying to create a circular plot with a color map that should be related with different temperature values acquired on a disk in order to verify the homogeneity of the heating, but despite my numerous trial and efforts it just wont work as i'd like it to be (i'm a newbie in programming).
Any ideas?
Thanks for your attention and have a nice day!

---

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

    x = np.arange(-2, 2, 0.01)
    y = np.arange(-2, 2, 0.01)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    Z = X**2 + Y**2 + 1 #np.sin(X) * np.cos(Y) * 2

    R = 4
    Z[Z>R] = 0





    colors = [(1,1,1), (0.99, 0.90, 0.68), (1, 0.87, 0.58), (0.93, 0.79, 0.53), (0.97, 0.71, 0.35), (0.84, 0.71, 0.27), (0.74, 0.48, 0.23), 
         (0.65, 0.44, 0.24), (0.56, 0.39, 0.23), (0.48, 0.32, 0.23),( 0.84, 0.53, 0.20), (0.21, 0.2, 0.17)]  # R -> G -> B
    n_bins = [100]  
    cmap_name = 'my_list'
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, figsize=(6, 9))
    fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.02, bottom=0.06, right=0.95, top=0.94, wspace=0.05)
    for n_bin, ax in zip(n_bins, axs.ravel()):

    cm = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(
    cmap_name, colors, N=n_bin)

    im = ax.imshow(Z, interpolation='nearest', origin='lower', cmap=cm)
    ax.set_title("N bins: %s" % n_bin)
    fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
```

This is a code that i'm trying to modify in order fit my purpose (temperature values correlation is still missing, i know...).

Comment: Can you add any code for reference and stuff you've already tried?

Comment: It's not much but is what i've got for now.